# Model callback is throughing an error(after_create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Why this is not saving values?

Everytime a new user gets created it should set default settings and create an entry in the settings model.
**The user/settings association works perfectly if I create it manually.** via **psql** or **rails c**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      after_create do
        if self.setting.nil? # check if user got settings most likely not
          # call settings model and create new default settings
          Setting.create(:user_id => self.id, :foo => "bar", :baz => true)
        end
      end
end
```

Yes the names are correct as well for example if I create settings for a user and I want to query the user settings I have to use:

```
current_user.setting.language
```

This is somehow stupid because it should be plural however it works so don't worry about any naming conventions or simple typos in my callback.

In fact it's actually not an error but the values just doesn't get saved.
Here is the process:

User creates a new account, this callback should create default settings  on the settings page there is a div which requires the settings id like so:

```
    <h2 data-settings_id="<%= current_user.setting.id %>" id="current_user" data-user="<%= current_user.id %>">Settings </h2>
```

If I create settings manually this page works fine - so I guess that the callback is not creating any settings since I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Notes: 
I use devise and I don't want to override any of those classes.
How to fix this? thanks

Comment: `so I guess ..` maybe you could just check it?

Comment: check what ? I did it's not creating any values ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your callback condition:

```
self.setting.nil?
```

Since `setting` is a relation it should return an **ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy** object which is much like an `Array` and checking with `nil?` will always return `false`, you need to check with `blank?` instead.

Something like this, should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create do
    if self.setting.blank? # check if user got settings most likely not
      # call settings model and create new default settings
      self.setting.create(:foo => "bar", :baz => true) # user_id will be set for us since we initiated the new object using the relation
    end
  end
end
```